# Build PhoneGap cordova app using ionic GUI and cordova js, angular js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have developed a pure ionic sample project.
But, I have a requirement to develop a phoneGap cordova app that uses a GUI built with the ionic framework and cordova javascript code to make network call and display the result on UI.

Is it possible to meet this requirement? And if so, how?

Comment: I don't see any problem here. Ionic is a JavaScript framework, so your writing JavaScript code, when programming an Ionic app...

Answer (score 0):

You need to first understand the relation between ionic framework and cordova.

this might help you :
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Cordova-and-Ionic

Once you created your ionic project,

```
$ ionic platform add android
```

`$ ionic run android`(if using a device for testing)

read here for more understanding about testing your app:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/testing.html

Also make sure that index.html file of your project includes :

```
<script src ="cordova.js"></script>
```

If you followed correct installation process, then you're project is ready to add cordova plugins and use them.

Hope this helped.